# how to send the params in http post request in angular service ( angular 2)

Tags: angular

My Requirement :

I am in process of developing a simple password reset feature. it has two components verify user ( email id and Date of joining) and forgot password (new pass,confirm pass). If it is a valid user then system should carry the data and route to next page forgot password, once the user enters the new pass and confirm pass, on click submit the pass should get reset.

Problem :

I am able to inject the data between components but not sure how to pass the data ( email id and Date ) as query string params in http post request in forgotpass.service.ts file which will call my backend to perform password reset operation.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Code snippet :

forgot password.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers,Response,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'

@Injectable()
export class ForgotpasswordService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  forgotpassword(forgot)

  {
    // public url = http://localhost:90/forgotpassword/
    var headers= new Headers();
    headers.append('content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    console.log("Connecting to Node js to change password");
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:90/forgotpassword/?email_id=test@gmail.com&date_id=03/30/2007",JSON.stringify(forgot),{headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json());    
  }

}
```

---

Forgotpass.component.ts

```
constructor(private forgotpasswordservice:ForgotpasswordService,private router: Router,public dialog:MdDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.forgot= '/?email_id='+this.email_id_inject+'&date_id='+this.date_id_inject;
  //   console.log(this.forgot);
  //  console.log(this.date_id_inject); 
  //  console.log(this.email_id_inject);

    }

   changepassword() 
    {
      const forgot ={
        pass_word:this.pass_word
      }
      this.forgotpasswordservice.forgotpassword(forgot).subscribe(forgot=> {
        console.log(forgot);

          if (forgot.success) 
          {
            ----success and route to login screen --
          }
          else 
          {
           --- failure error
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically with POST requests, you would send additional data in the body of the request. Since you are setting the request content-type header to `application/json`, you should be sending json in the body. You can simply do this by passing in the json as the second parameter to `http.post`

```
return this.http.post(
    "http://localhost:90/forgotpassword/?email_id=test@gmail.com&date_id=03/30/2007",
    forgot, // pass json into the body of the request
    {headers:headers}
)
    .map(res => res.json());
```

If you truly need to pass the data as query params you can manually add them to your url or use URLSearchParams

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('email_id', forgot.email_id);

return this.http.post(
    "http://localhost:90/forgotpassword/?email_id=test@gmail.com&date_id=03/30/2007",
    {},
    {headers:headers, params:params} // add params to options to be appended to url as query params
)
```

Note: UrlSearchParams is used for the old HTTPModule, when using the new HTTPClientModule, use HttpParams instead.